# How to develop offline support website?

Tags: html

I want to give offline support to website so user can access website even in absence of internet as of offline Gmail.

Please suggest technology?

Ans: HTML5 is the answer for this. I hv added detailed answer below.

Thanks,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage. Have you heard of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at HTML5 Application Cache: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/. Note that this is not yet a cross-browser technology and will not work in older browsers.

Comment: Application Cache is an HTML5 technology, and should be compatible with PHP or (in theory) any other server-side platform.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is the answer for this. In HTML5 using LocalStorage and Tag.

Attribute offline script Triggers when the document goes offline and after that you can server content from localstorage.

more on web_storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**Edited:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/